# Maven failure to find maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I try to compile maven web project with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that when I try compile it I get the following errors:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project inferx-d2aserver: Could
>   not resolve dependencies for project
>   com.inferx:inferx-d2aserver:war:4.0: The following artifacts could not
>   be resolved: maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3,
>   maven-plugins:maven-findbugs-plugin:plugin:1.3.1,
>   org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE: Failure to find
>   maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3 in
>   http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release was cached in
>   the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of com.springsource.repository.bundles.release has
>   elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1] [ERROR]

I use Apache Maven 3.0.3, Java: 1.7.0 OS: Windows 7 (64 bit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the same case since my dependencies is different. I got similar error message with the same dependencies error so I removed both dependencies from `~/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.3/jaxen-1.1.3.pom` and the project is compile fine now.

Comment: Same trick worked for me in apache ivy. Removed failed dependencies from ~/.ant/cache/jaxen/jaxen/ivy-1.1.3.xml and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks! Of course adding an 'exclusion' to the jaxen dependency helps too.

Comment: Ugrading this dependency to jaxen 1.1.6 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing similar issue. I just excluded jaxen from Jdom dependency and it worked for me.

**jdom 1.1.2 includes jaxen 1.1.3 which imports those artifact**s.

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
               <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

It look like your pom or parent pom contains a wrong definition of the [maven-coberatura-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) which should be fixed first. Furthermore remove the folder in your local repository.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message related to [cobertura version,](http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-cobertura-plugin/) it looks like you may be having a `pom.xml` corresponding to `maven 1`.

The following are maven 1.x versions of the plugins and not supported.

- maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3,
- maven-plugins:maven-findbugs-plugin:plugin:1.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Removing the pom is not the solution; in future builds may be you need them. Best solution according to my opinion is to modify the `POM` of corresponding jars. Like if you are getting error because of any jar; actually there is the dependency defined in its POM. So use `<exclude>`. That will work for sure.