# Couldn't run build using Maven because of an error in pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I am trying to build a new Maven project in Eclipse.
In my pom.xml, I got an error which says

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Missing artifact maven-plugins:maven-findbugs-plugin:plugin:1.3.1
    - Missing artifact maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3

Here is my dependency code for "cobertura" in pom.xml:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <type>plugin</type>
    </dependency>
```

I tried adding repositories as below, but still didn't work.

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.maven-plugins.sourceforge.net</id>
        <name>maven plug-in repository</name>
        <url>http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/repository</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.ibiblio.org-maven</id>
        <name>ibiblio repository</name>
        <url>http://www.ibiblio.org/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Links to Maven plugins here
[http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-findbugs-plugin/announcements/announcement-1.3.1.txt](http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-cobertura-plugin/announcements/announcement-1.3.txt)

http://maven-plugins.sourceforge.net/maven-cobertura-plugin/announcements/announcement-1.3.txt

I don't want to do Manual installation for these plugins. I need to install them automatically by declaring them in pom.xml

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295458/maven-failure-to-find-maven-pluginsmaven-cobertura-plugin/8295903#8295903?

Answer (score 15):

As a related issue, I found that e.g. jaxen-1.1.3 references the above maven1 artifacts.  The POM editor in Eclipse shows you the dependency hierarchy.  It added the following for selecting explicit excludes:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>maven-findbugs-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Also jdom 1.1.2 includes jaxen 1.1.3 which imports those artifacts. The same fix applies into jdom dependency. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

These are maven 1 plugins and will not work with maven 2.   These are the current versions of the plugins.

- [cobertura maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/) 2.5.1
- [findbugs maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/) 2.3.3

You would define plugins within `<plugins>` tag and not `<dependencies>` tag. Also note the change in `groupId` and `artifactId` for these plugins below...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>   
 </plugin>

 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>    
  </plugin>
```

Comment: This does not work, because jaxen explicitly demands cobertura 1.3 and findbugs 1.3.1.