# Alter ivy.xml file called in as transitive dependency

Tags: ivy

I am using ivy to resolve dependencies, the direct dependency I have is for jdom with the entry on ivy.xml as

```
     <dependency org="org.jdom" name="jdom" rev="2.0.2"/>
```

This calls in several other jars as transitive dependencies - unfortunately one, jaxen, has a non working dependency as per [Jaxen bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JAXEN-217) and various questions on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295458/maven-failure-to-find-maven-pluginsmaven-cobertura-plugin) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337616/couldnt-run-build-using-maven-because-of-an-error-in-pom-xml). Unfortunately these questions are answered with a fix to a maven pom.

My question is what can I do in my ivy setup to use a corrected ivy file for jaxen or just suppress jaxen trying to load findbugs and cobertura?

Comment: As this has several down votes I would ask why as this is not directly in the documentation and seems to me to have all the details needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ivy allows to [exclude](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/artifact-exclude.html) specified  [dependencies](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependencies.html) from resolution.

This will exclude jaxen from the dependency:

```
<dependency org="org.jdom" name="jdom" rev="2.0.2">
  <exclude module="jaxen"/>
</dependency>
```

This will exclude cobertura and findbugs

```
<dependency org="org.jdom" name="jdom" rev="2.0.2">
  <exclude name="maven-cobertura-plugin" />
  <exclude name="maven-findbugs-plugin" />
</dependency>
```