# Maven Dependencies can't be resolved

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-3

I'm using *Apache Maven3* and since two or three days some dependencies can't be resolved any more, which first have not had a problem. To be more specific its:

1. `maven-findbgs-plugin:plugin:1.3.1`
2. `maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3`

Shouldn't they be included by maven itself?

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  <name>xyz</name>
  <description>xyz</description>
  <repositories>
      <repository>  
        <id>prime-repo</id>  
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
        <layout>default</layout>  
    </repository>  
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>${springwebflow-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Communication to PowerTAC Server -->

      <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-rev-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>activecluster</groupId>
    <artifactId>activecluster</artifactId>
    <version>20040423.075722</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xbean</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javacc</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>




    <!-- Sun Mojarra JSF 2 runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- PrimeFaces component library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powertac</groupId>
        <artifactId>server-interface</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <java-version>1.5</java-version>
    <springframework-version>3.0.5.RELEASE</springframework-version>
    <springwebflow-version>2.3.0.RELEASE</springwebflow-version>
    <springsecurity-version>3.0.3.RELEASE</springsecurity-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
  </properties>
  <groupId>org.powertac</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Within my IDE (Springsource Tool Suite) I'm getting the following warning 
[image: Warning of IDE]

When I do something like "mvn compile" in my shell the following error occurs:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xcz 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact javacc:javacc:jar:4.0 has been relocated to net.java.dev.
javacc:javacc:jar:4.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.193s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Dec 04 10:11:47 CET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/160M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xyz: Could not resolve depend
encies for project xyz:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following a
rtifacts could not be resolved: maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3,
 maven-plugins:maven-findbugs-plugin:plugin:1.3.1, Failure to find maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin
:1.3 in http://repository.primefaces.org was cached in the local repository, res
olution will not be reattempted until the update interval of prime-repo has elap
sed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
lutionException
```

When I insert the below mentioned plugins and do `mvn site` the following error message occurs:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building xyz 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/2.2.1/prime
faces-2.2.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.1 is missing, no depende
ncy information available
[WARNING] The artifact javacc:javacc:jar:4.0 has been relocated to net.java.dev.
javacc:javacc:jar:4.0
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/2.2.1/prime
faces-2.2.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.609s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Dec 04 10:35:51 CET 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/160M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xyz: Could not resolve depend
encies for project xyz:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following a
rtifacts could not be resolved: maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3,
 maven-plugins:maven-findbugs-plugin:plugin:1.3.1, org.primefaces:primefaces:jar
:2.2.1: Failure to find maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin:plugin:1.3 in http:
//repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not
 be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are
forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyReso
```

Any help is highly apprechiated.

Comment: Well, no, nothing is auto-included. Posting your pom.xml might be useful. And what error do you exactly get when performing which action?

Comment: @yair I'ce updated my description. Hope that it's now sufficient...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven failure to find maven-plugins:maven-cobertura-plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295458/maven-failure-to-find-maven-pluginsmaven-cobertura-plugin)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should add those two plugins to your pom.

For cobertura, see [this page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html).

For findbugs, see [this page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html).

----- UPDATED -----

OK, I found the problem. It appears that you depend on jdom 1.1.2, which depends on jaxen 1.1.3 of which artifact is broken.

You can either try another jdom version or add to your pom the snapshot described in [this site](http://blog.cedarsoft.com/?p=499). Worked for me when I ran your pom on my PC. I copied the snapshot:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3</version>
  <!-- http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JAXEN-217 -->
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-cobertura-plugin</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>maven-plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-findbugs-plugin</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I've included them but without success. Ive updated the description above with the error message.

Answer (score 3):

For those who try to fix it with Ivy. This one worked for me:

```xml
<dependency org="jaxen" name="jaxen" rev="1.1.4"/>
<dependency org="net.sourceforge.cobertura" name="cobertura" rev="1.9.4.1"/>
<dependency org="com.google.code.findbugs" name="findbugs" rev="2.0.1"/>
<dependency org="org.jdom" name="jdom" rev="2.0.2">
  <exclude module="jaxen"/>
  <exclude name="maven-cobertura-plugin"/>
  <exclude name="maven-findbugs-plugin"/>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in your local repository (`normaly in <home>/.m2`), where the artifacts should be. You'll find `<artifactname>.lastUpdated` files there. delete those and try again.

Possibly the artifacts failed to load due to network problems and now aren't even checked.

Comment: Unfortunately this was not successful. I deleted the files and updated the project configuration inside my IDE. The files were created again but the error message is still here. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you get when you past the URL maven is accessing in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the POM editor in Eclipse to see the dependency graph.  It quickly showed my that jaxen-1.1.3 includes old maven1 dependencies.  Eclipse even offers excluding them on the spot.  Nice.